# PayPal IPN for subscription - Works partially

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am running PayPal Subscription and I am trying to fire database writes based upon the response received. Up until yesterday, the code was working correctly. But today, strangely, the code stopped firing emails upon receiving payments. I am not sure if this is a glitch on PayPal's side or mine. I don't think its an issue with my code because I stripped a lot of code from it and I am currently using the basic version of IPN for payments tracking, but even then it does not make database inserts or fires emails.

I also searched SO for possible solutions & even implemented the ones that I found were close to my answer. But unfortunately, they didn't work. So here's my IPN code:

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



$notify_email =  "myemail@domain.com"; //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "host"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "user"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "password"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "dbname"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR
} 
else 
{

    mail($notify_email, "IPN Triggered 1", "IPN Triggered 1");  

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        //Already used this
        //$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        //Using this to see if it sends response
        $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);


        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
        {   
            mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED 1", "VERIFIED 1");

            //create MySQL connection
            $Connect = mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
            or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


            //select database
            $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
            or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


            $fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
            $fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");

            //check if transaction ID has been processed before
            $checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".$txn_id."'";
            $sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
            $nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);

            if ($nm == 0)
            {
                //execute query
                if ($txn_type == "cart")
                {
                    $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

                     $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Cart - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

                     for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) 
                     {
                         $itemname = "item_name".$i;
                         $itemnumber = "item_number".$i;
                         $on0 = "option_name1_".$i;
                         $os0 = "option_selection1_".$i;
                         $on1 = "option_name2_".$i;
                         $os1 = "option_selection2_".$i;
                         $quantity = "quantity".$i;

                         $struery = "insert into paypal_cart_info(txnid,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,invoice,custom) values ('".$txn_id."','".$_POST[$itemnumber]."','".$_POST[$itemname]."','".$_POST[$on0]."','".$_POST[$os0]."','".$_POST[$on1]."','".$_POST[$os1]."','".$_POST[$quantity]."','".$invoice."','".$custom."')";
         $result = mysql_query($struery) or die("Cart - paypal_cart_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

                     }
                }
                else
                {
                     $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

                     $result = mysql_query("insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')") or die("Default - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
                }

            // send an email in any case
             //echo "Verified";
                mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
            }
            else 
            {
                // send an email
                mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
            }

            //subscription handling branch
            if ( $txn_type == "subscr_signup"  ||  $txn_type == "subscr_payment"  ) 
            {
                // insert subscriber payment info into paypal_payment_info table
                $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
                $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Subscription - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


                 // insert subscriber info into paypal_subscription_info table
                $strQuery2 = "insert into paypal_subscription_info(subscr_id , sub_event, subscr_date ,subscr_effective,period1,period2, period3, amount1 ,amount2 ,amount3,  mc_amount1,  mc_amount2,  mc_amount3, recurring, reattempt,retry_at, recur_times, username ,password, payment_txn_id, subscriber_emailaddress, datecreation) values ('".$subscr_id."', '".$txn_type."','".$subscr_date."','".$subscr_effective."','".$period1."','".$period2."','".$period3."','".$amount1."','".$amount2."','".$amount3."','".$mc_amount1."','".$mc_amount2."','".$mc_amount3."','".$recurring."','".$reattempt."','".$retry_at."','".$recur_times."','".$username."','".$password."', '".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$fecha."')";
                $result = mysql_query($strQuery2) or die("Subscription - paypal_subscription_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


                mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");

            }
        }

        // if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
        {
            // log for manual investigation
            mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
        }
    }

    fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

What I have noticed that up until the following line, the code is working correctly: `mail($notify_email, "IPN Triggered 1", "IPN Triggered 1");` I am receiving this email with the subject line **IPN Triggered 1**. So up until this line, its working good.

Once it gets into the while loop, it's **not** triggering the mails. There is a mail function in `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)` but it's not getting triggered. This was working yesterday, but today it's not!!! None of the mail functions that are within the `while` loop are triggered.

**What can be done to fix this issue so that I can perform both the operations i.e. write to database and send mails?**

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, I stripped the code that inserts into database & it still behaves the same way. I really feel that PayPal Sandbox is not sending the response. Can anyone please confirm this?

The other half of the code that I modified, looks like this now:

```
if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR
} 
else 
{

    mail($notify_email, "IPN Triggered 1", "IPN Triggered 1");  

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        //Already used this
        //$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        //Using this to see if it sends response
        $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);


        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
        {   
            mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED 1", "VERIFIED 1");

        }
        // if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
        {
            // log for manual investigation
            mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
        }
    }

    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Here's the revised code:

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);



if (!$fp) 
{
// HTTP ERROR

} 
else 
{
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
        {
            mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED 1", "VERIFIED 1");

        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
        {

            mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
        }
    }

    fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```